# How "PScustomobject" work in powershell 2.0?

Tags: powershell

how does this script work in powershell 2.0

Import-Module -Name WebAdministration

$servers = Get-Content D:\Utilidades\servidores.txt

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  Invoke-Command -Computername $server -ScriptBlock { import-module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:SSLBindings | ForEach-Object -Process `
            {
                if ($_.Sites)
                {

`$certificate = Get-ChildItem -Path CERT:LocalMachine/My | 
                Where-Object -Property Thumbprint -EQ -Value $_.Thumbprint

                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    Sites                         = $_.Sites.Value
                    FriendlyName                  = $certificate.FriendlyName
                    Fecha_de_Expiracion           = $certificate.NotAfter
                    Thumbprint                    = $certificate.Thumbprint


                }
             }
         }


     } | Select Sites,FriendlyName,Fecha_de_Expiracion,Thumbprint,PSComputerName | Export-Csv -force -Append D:\Utilidades\Output.csv  }`

Comment: What part is confusing you?  `[PsCustomObject]@{}` is basically the same as `New-Object PSObject -Property @{}`.

Comment: The problem is this script doesn't work with 2008 servers in the txt file.

Comment: Doesn't work how?  What errors do you get?  Edit the question, and include error messages.   You mention '2008', but do you mean '2008r2'?   Earlier version of 2008 are EOL.  Have you updated the management framework on your systems?   What is the Powershell version on those servers.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're not getting any output because the path on your PSDrives is missing the backslash

```
CERT:LocalMachine > CERT:\LocalMachine
IIS:SSL bindings > IIS:\SSLBindings
```